# boost threadpool - documentation and examples

Tags: boost, multithreading

I'm looking for documentation on boost::threadpool.  I downloaded the source and documentation zip files.  The documentation directory is just about empty.  It says to look at src/examples/mergesort.cpp.  It ain't there.  In fact, there is no src/examples directory.

Anyone know if there is a Roseta Stone, and if so where?

Comment: Please provide a link, there is more than one threadpool implementation for boost.

Comment: I didn't know that. I snagged the stuff here:  http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/  

Let me turn it around.  Where are the implementations?  What's the greatest if not latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Boost Vault - Concurrent Programming](https://github.com/boost-vault/Concurrent-Programming) there are a couple of libs, check async and boost.task. The documentation is included in the packages. Personally, I have used async and was pleased. Make sure you find the docs, there ARE there in the dir tree. afaik there are no more docs for threadpool.sourceforge.net